# Box-shadow does not work for section

Tags: css

I'm failing to achieve shadow in a section. It should look like this.

[image]

Do you see slight shadow under bottom border.

My code look like that:

```
.top-bar {
  background-color:#e0f2f1;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

I wonder why it fails to work out. Maybe my syntax is not correct. If you need more details, please refer to my project in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/zBbxyW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to the top-bar

`box-shadow` will work only on **non inherited positioned `section`**

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6hnzv45w/)**

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.top-bar {
  background-color:#e0f2f1;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px green;
 position: relative;
}

.paragraph-container {
  margin:0 auto;
}

#top-bar-paragraph {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
  opacity:0.7;
}

.project-name-class {
  background-color:white;
  height:200px;
}

.col-md-8 img {
  margin-top:30px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
      <p id = "top-bar-paragraph">this is not official wikipedia page please refer to <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/" target="_blank">wikipedia.org</a></p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="project-name-class">
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
      
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/nzmai/image/upload/v1471508759/Wikipedia-Search_n8wfpx.png" alt="image" />
          
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
</section>
```

Comment: @SyamPillai box-shadow will work in all elements not only relatively positioned elements

Answer (score 0):

You have controlled the height of whole parent container to be 50px whereas you need to give style to the top pod alone.

Actually your shadow in applied but it is hidden behind your `.container` div,
you can see that by giving margin(for visually understanding,not the answer)

```
.top-bar{margin:10px;}
```

Apply style to `#top-bar-paragraph` instead of `.top-bar`

```
#top-bar-paragraph {
  background-color:#e0f2f1;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px red;
}
```

fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/6hnzv45w/1/)**

Comment: You have given `box-shadow` to paragraph. The question title is **Box-shadow does not work for section**

Comment: @SyamPillai yes ,that's beacuse height has been given to whole parent but inside contents are there . As mentioned in answer give margin to see that box-shaodw which is already applied.

Comment: Giving margin will affect the postion of below elements also. it will go down `10px` as per your example. But positioning to relative may not affect others. Check it

Comment: @SyamPillai specifiying margin is not an answer that allows us to see that box-shadow works, the problem here is the HTML structure that's why i have applied style to `#top-bar-paragraph`

Comment: One more problem is if you are giving  `box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px red;`. Margin at the bottom should be 14px to get an **uncut** box-shadow. And then the below section will also move down `14px`